# Chrome doesn't cache images/js/css

Tags: caching, google-chrome, http-headers

When Chrome loads my website, it checks the server for updated versions of files before it shows them. (Images/Javascript/CSS) It gets a 304 from the server because I never edit external javascript, css or images.

What I want it to do, is display the images without even checking the server.

Here are the headers:

```
Connection:keep-alive    
Date:Tue, 03 Aug 2010 21:39:32 GMT    
ETag:"2792c73-b1-48cd0909d96ed"    
Expires:Thu, 02 Sep 2010 21:39:32 GMT    
Server:Apache/Nginx/Varnish
```

How do I make it not check the server?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191150/chrome-not-caching-css-file-the-caching-works-for-js-png-files ?

Answer (score 121):

Make sure you have the `disable cache` checkbox unchecked/disabled in the Developer Tools.

Comment: This helped me solve the same issue. In-case you all are stuck, in the developer tools, click the gear icon at the bottom-right.

Comment: And to think I was about to write an image serving page, just to enforce cache control.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: I just threw my arms up into the air demanding god to punish me for my stupidity. Also had cache disabled...

Comment: The problem existed between _my_ keyboard and chair.

Answer (score 90):

What do your request headers look like?

Chrome will set max-age:0 on the request's Cache-Control header [if you press Enter in the location bar](http://techblog.tilllate.com/2008/11/14/clientside-cache-control/). If you visit your page using a hyperlink, it should use the cache, as expected.

Comment: Request headers are also set to `max-age:0` for page refreshing, which makes sense. Test using links..

Comment: @Jacob Krall, may I reverse the question. What can I do to fore Chrome **always** hit server for an image url, even if I visit page using a hyperlink. I have set all cache control headers, etc. but chrome never refreshes this images when navigation through anchor. IE and FF works as expected, refreshes them every time.

Comment: @thedk: what have you set the cache-control header to?

Comment: @thedk: old question, but: for an apache these htaccess commands will do: `FileETag None;
  Header unset ETag;
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
  Header set Pragma "no-cache";
  Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"` (replace ";" with linebreaks!) - if it's just for development you can enable "disable cache" in chromes developer tool's settings menu

Comment: @it's other way around

Comment: @ChrisNicholson: this works for me just now. I used the back/forward buttons to eliminate server round-trip.

Comment: I'm seeing max-age=0 regardless of how I interact with the site.

Comment: A).  Chrome will also set max-age:0 if you hit **refresh** in addition to using the location bar.  B)  Both these behaviors appear to be the case in Firefox as well.  I can't speak to other browsers.

Comment: With disable cache in developers tools off: F5, refresh, and enter in the address bar all won't work for all static assets. Somehow, some started to get served form disk cache and some not. Back and forth made all static assets got served from disk cache, leading for me to the conclusion that caching is working :)

Comment: This makes sense. I think it's because, for average users, hitting enter on the link bar should equate to hitting refresh.

Answer (score 60):

Wow! I was facing the same issue for quite some time.

I'll tell you why you were facing this issue. Your headers are just fine. You receive a 304 because of the way you are trying to refresh the page. There a mainly 3 ways -

1. Press enter in the address box. You will observe chrome reads the file from the cache first and does not go to the server at all.
2. Press f5, this would verify if the file has become stale (probably that is how you are refreshing)
3. Press Ctrl+f5, this is unconditional reload of all static resources.

So basically - you should press the return key in the address bar. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Press Enter in address box still reloads. Copy pasting url in new or same tab and then pressing Enter does not.

Comment: Google Chrome version 58.0.3029.110 - Clicking Enter in the Address bar did not work for me, but copy-paste of the url in a new tab, and then Enter worked... because reasons... :)

Comment: @Tushar - is there any way by which I can avoid sending the request to server in case of F5? As of now it sends the request to server, then server responds back with 304 and then it gets loaded from cache. I want browser to load it from cache directly when someone press F5, as my resources are available in disk cache.

Answer (score 50):

For me, it was self-signed certificate:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110649

In the above link the Chromium Developer marked the bug: `#WontFix` because the rule is: "Any error with the certificate means the page will not be cached."

Therefore Chrome doesn't cache resources from servers with self-signed certificate.

Comment: There are a lot of good answers on the page, but this has to be the crucial first step of any https pages

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: @TumainiMosha you can add self-signed certificate to your browser storage. Than it'll go green and will be cached.

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: It is cacheing now. On version 63 (mac OS)

Comment: Nice thanks I was scratching my head why it cached on firefox and not with chrome

Comment: This was the reason for me as well, thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

If you want Chrome to cache your JS/CSS files - the server will need to set a "Cache-Control" header. It should look like:

Cache-Control:max-age=86400 (if you want to cache resources for a day).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here are the new headers:

Cache-Control:max-age=2592000
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Tue, 03 Aug 2010 21:57:36 GMT
ETag:"2792c73-b1-48cd0909d96ed"
Expires:Thu, 02 Sep 2010 21:57:36 GMT
Server:Apache/Nginx/Varnish

but it still doesn't work. Chrome still checks the server for modifications.

Comment: How are you making sure that Chrome checks the server for modifications ? Are you using something like Fiddler ?

Comment: @Rahul Ctrl-Shift-I in Chrome

Comment: Note chrome caches JS/CSS by default, without a cache-control header, at least for regular page loads.  On reload or shift-reload it fetches new from the server.

Comment: On devconsole, if chrome loads cached file you should see (from cache) on the size column against the file

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for

`Cache-Control: immutable`

Comment: Not that currently then only browsers that support this are Firefox and Edge.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Browser_compatibility

Comment: chrome and safari also have support for it. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936772/which-browsers-support-cache-control-immutable
I believe this is the solution if you don't control client.