# Is using a CDN for jQuery (or other static files/scripts) really a good idea?

Tags: javascript, cdn

It says everywhere to use a CDN, such as Google's or Microsoft's AJAX CDN to load static script libraries, such as jQuery in my case.

I don't understand how this is really helpful to make my site any faster. In firebug, I'm getting around 300ms both for Google and Microsoft AJAX servers when I load jQuery, and in Chrome, I'm getting around 100ms (dunno what creates the difference, no downloads going on, tried both several times, but anyway that's not the point), my site will have an estimated average of 30 to 40ms response time when I deploy. How can loading the files the CDN do any good to my site? It will make everything even worse!

I understand that when I visit many sites using, say, jQuery from Google's CDN, it will have to "download" the script only once for a very long time, but my browser still tries to connect to the Google's server, and ask for the script file, and then receive 304 not modified status code. During this round trip of 200ms (average of Chrome and FF), I wait. But if I hosted the script file myself, then it will (down)load MUCH faster, about five times, which is an important factor for user experience. Maybe 200ms is not a VERY BIG deal, but it's still a difference and I want to know why it's recommended to use a CDN instead of hosting files ourselves. In the end, after one-time load, the browser will cache the script for my site as well and if I use CDN, browser will ask the CDN for the script anyway which will lag my website.

**Update:** I am from Turkey, and that may be the primary reason to have high roundtrips. Most of my visitors will be from here, so I'm asking would it be beneficial for **my site** hosted on servers in Turkey, and **users of my site** who are also at Turkey, to use CDN. Definitely not good for roundtrips, but maybe I'm missing out something.

Comment: You ask if it's a good idea, then state that for you it's not, then you ask why it's recommended - what is the question?

Comment: 200ms to do a round trip to google to get a 304 not modified is VERY slow.  I would expect it to take < 20ms for most people. I just tried it and it took 17ms

Comment: they all mean the same thing: i am asking if it's really a good idea (as most people say) or not, giving my own reasons on why I think it is not.

Comment: @Mr. Disapointment, the question is "Why do people recommend CDNs because my experience says they are slower than downloading the library from my server", it's a valid question, i just think that the answer is "your experience is not indicative of most people's experience"

Comment: @Ben Robinson: where are you located at? I'm in Turkey, and the roundtrip is as I've stated.

Comment: @Ben Robinson: Excuse me, but I don't believe I stated the question was invalid; both _should I?_ and _why?_ are valid, but they are distinct questions - my point is that it is not properly articulated and could well be subjective.

Comment: @Ben I imagine this has a lot to do with the fact the request is being made from Turkey.

Comment: @Moses yes, i think so either, updated the question.

Comment: @can poyrazoğlu: google CDN 5 times slower than your server? are you a victim of this? http://encosia.com/cripple-the-google-cdns-caching-with-a-single-character/

Comment: @naveen nope, i have nothing related to SSL. my site is pure "insecure" http, including script references.

Comment: Chrome will set max-age:0 on the request's Cache-Control header if you press Enter in the location bar. If you visit your page using a hyperlink, it should use the cache, as expected. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401049/chrome-doesnt-cache-images-js-css/5799781#5799781

Comment: @Jacob: That would seem like very odd behavior to me. I just tried it and am not seeing it. Pasted a URL into the address bar and pressed Enter. jquery.js was loaded from cache, not even an `if-modified-since` request was sent.

Comment: Indeed. It's very possible that its behavior has changed since I discovered that; Chrome moves quickly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Two part answer:**

- You shouldn't be seeing 304s
- But is it a good idea?

### You Shouldn't Be Seeing 304s

> I understand that when I visit many sites using, say, jQuery from Google's CDN, it will have to "download" the script only once for a very long time, but my browser still tries to connect to the Google's server, and ask for the script file, and then receive 304 not modified status code.

It shouldn't, not if it's respecting the `Cache-Control` header:

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000
```

...which says from the date on the resource, the browser can cache it for up to a year. No need for any HTTP request *at all* (and that's what I see in Chrome unless I force it, no request *at all*, just a note saying "from cache"; fired up Firefox and made sure Firebug was on for all pages, came to StackOverflow for the first time in a *long* time with Firefox [which I only use for testing], and sure enough, it didn't issue any request for jquery at all).

E.g., maybe it takes 200ms for a 304 response, but if your browser is caching correctly, it'll be 0ms for a load-from-cache.

The full set of relevant headers I see on a forced request are:

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000
Date:Wed, 17 Aug 2011 21:56:52 GMT
Expires:Thu, 16 Aug 2012 21:56:52 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 01 Apr 2011 21:23:55 GMT
```

...so my browser shouldn't have to request that path again for nearly a year.

See @Dave Ward's comment below: To get max caching results, use the full release number, e.g.:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<!--                               very specific ---^^^^^                      -->
```

rather than

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<!--                               very generic ----^                      -->
```

### Okay, but is it a good idea?

That's entirely up to you. Even with a fallback like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
    document.write("<scr" + "ipt src='/my/local/jquery.js'></scr" + "ipt>");
}
</script>
```

...or similar, the UX if the CDN is down is going to be ***awful***. The browser is going to spin for ages trying to connect to it. That kind of fallback will only help if the CDN quickly replies with a failure, which is unlikely.

This means if Google's CDN goes down, you would have to quickly adjust what you're serving to use your local copy instead. So defending against that becomes a monitoring exercise (of Google's servers; don't overdo it or they'll be displeased) with a failover at the server level to start serving pages with a local path. (Or a Microsoft path, on the theory that Google and Microsoft probably aren't sharing underlying CDN technology, given how well they get along.)

For me, the answer for most sites is probably: Go ahead and use the CDN, react if and when Google's CDN for libraries goes down. The flip side is: If you're happy with your overall page load performance loading it from your server, little harm in doing that until or unless traffic is high enough that you're looking to eke every last bit of performance out of things. But lots (and lots and lots) of sites rely on Google's CDN, if it goes down, your site will be far from alone in failing...

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that the caching is severely limited if you use anything but a specific 1.n.n reference (even for new point-releases - 1.n.0). A common mistake is to reference the latest point-release, like 1.6 instead of 1.6.2, which drops the local caching window to nearly nil.

Comment: weirdly, chrome is caching only "sometimes" (as it's being forced into a full refresh, which I'm NOT doing), and firefox doesn't cache it at all. it it worked as it explained, it would be the perfect solution, but it doesn't work on my browsers correctly, and potentially my users' browsers too.

Comment: no it wasn't. I don't know, maybe it was a cache issue with my browser or it was ignoring the cache for debug. it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Could give you [6,953 reasons why I still let Google host jQuery for me](http://encosia.com/6953-reasons-why-i-still-let-google-host-jquery-for-me/).

The main advantages being

1. Decreased Latency
2. Increased parallelism
3. Better caching

Answer (score 1):

one important note on why Firefox doesn't cache what it should cache !
FIREBUG has an small feature called "Disable Browser Cache"
developers and designers most of the times turn it on and so firefox don't cache anything **even  when firebug is not active** !!
so just open 'firebug' > go to 'Net' tab > [image: Right click on tab and unmark it .]

i think this is very costly bug in firebug which cause a lot of bandwidth wasting for poor developers !

Answer (score 0):

The point is, that if many websites reference the CDN-based versions, chances are high that users coming to your site already have the script in their cache.

Comment: I initially thought that was the correct answer to his question as well. But if you reread his question, OP knows this, his question refers to checking of http status, not loading of the file itself.

Comment: i understand that but that doesn't benefit me in any way. are there any other really good reasons?