# I see 200 instead of 304 for cached URLs

Tags: http, caching, http-caching

Recently my developer enabled site caching per page as well as assets. The response code for assets is 304, as desired, but the pages return 200:

`/offers/brand-new-car HTTP/1.1" **200**`

Refreshing the page (using the F5 shortcut) doesn’t seem to help.

Here is a sample log:

```
37.190.212.157 - - [06/Mar/2015:11:10:45 +0100] "GET /offers/brand-new-car HTTP/1.1" **200** 11998 "http://domain.com/cars" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36"
```

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Show the request and response headers, capture them using Fiddler. Refresh not using F5 but by [pressing enter in the address bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401049/chrome-doesnt-cache-images-js-css).

Comment: There are a lot of ways to implement caching. We get something is wrong, but we can’t pinpoint the problem with this little information. Could you please tell us *how* your developer implemented the caching? Check your server configurations (`.htaccess` for Apache) or application code.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/5tK3 here is screen how that`s look 
I also tried to Enter instead of F5 but same result 200

Here is .htaccess setting

Header unset ETag
FileETag None

## Set cache-control header

Header set Cache-Control "public"


Header set Cache-Control "private"

## Insert filter

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

## Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip

## MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine

BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

## Don't compress images

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
.(?:gif|jpeg|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

## Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content

Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

## PageSpeed

ExpiresActive On
Header set Connection keep-alive

## compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hour"