# koa-static not following max-age

Tags: http, koa

I am using koa-static to serve my assets.
I have set max-age to a minute for now 60000ms (as described in the docs)

For testing purposes, I am using a big image as a background in my page, but it seems that the browser still re-downloads it every time the page is opened anyway...

Here is the related code:

```
var app        = require('koa')(),
    serve      = require('koa-static');

app.use(serve('./public', {
  maxage: 60000,
}))
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is not a problem with your browser instead of koa-static? I tried your example as is, but instead of using a browser i used curl to check out the headers:

if you

`curl -I http://localhost:3000/img.png`

You will see that the max-age header is set to one minute as desired.
It seems the cache-control was set to what we wanted, so it must be your browser doing something tricky with the headers. For example, if you are using chrome, it will set max-age=0 in certain situations:

[Chrome doesn't cache images/js/css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401049/chrome-doesnt-cache-images-js-css)

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem! Go Koa! It's too fun

Answer (score 0):

You should [koa-etag](https://github.com/koajs/etag), just add example code in your project.