# HTTP caching: is ETag only used *after* cached content has expired

Tags: html, caching

So, with some content, the server sends a `Cache-Control` header indicating that the content can be cached for up to 120 seconds, and also an `ETag` header with a sort of hash of the content.

When the browser next requests the content again (same URL), and assuming we're still within the 120 seconds, does the browser just use the local cached content, regardless of whether it has previously received the ETag and regardless of what the `ETag` might say about the freshness of the content?

That seems to be what is suggested [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en) (under section "Validating cached responses with ETags").

However, I have a situation where a request for content from the browser seems to be returning with headers that *should* allow caching for the next request, but it never seems to.

This is the Response Header from Chrome:

```
access-control-allow-origin:*
cache-control:private, max-age=300
date:Fri, 03 Jul 2015 21:22:33 GMT
etag:W/"208-nZVotiUd/tgf0oV0tBzi8w"
```

And the Request Header:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
If-None-Match:W/"208-nZVotiUd/tgf0oV0tBzi8w"
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
```

And under the General section:

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
```

The status code above suggests that the browser knows that the content has not changed (via a `304 response`), which means that did send the request off to the server.  That is despite the fact that the content has been (should have been) cached locally, and still within the cache period.

So why was the content not just fetched from cache?

What has me slightly suspicious is the `Cache-Control:max-age=0` in the request header... that presumably was put there by Chrome, but... why?  and what effect does it have?  I thought `Cache-Control` was set by the server, not requested from the browser?

Edit: I'm seeing something similar with the remote js libraries loaded in the html... the response header suggests that caching should be used, but the remote js is fetched afresh every time with a time delay... despite also getting a `304 response`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the way in which you load the page in the browser has an effect on the way in which cached resources are fetched.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16510707/4070848).  I was reloading the page each time by hitting F5, and it seems that this forces the browser to check whether the resources need to be fetched again, even if the locally cached copy is still apparently valid.  But if you reload the page by clicking in the address bar, and hitting enter, it follows the cache-control policy for the relevant content.  That's my understanding anyway.  So in future when I'm looking at how my page contents are being cached, I'm not just blindly going to hit F5, I'm going to reload the page by hitting enter in the address bar.