# Nginx - after enable http2 doesn't cache js and css, (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, css, caching, nginx, browser-cache

Before I enable http2 on nginx, I can have js and css file cached, but after that, I found the cache doesn't work on those 2 types of files.
Is that expected?

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
#ssl
listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;

ssl_certificate /opt/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /opt/server.key;

# Statistic Files
location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico|uploadFiles/|template/) {
  root /opt/nodejsblog/public;
  access_log off;
  expires 1y;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
}

# Proxy to backend load balance servers, connect to upstream
location / {
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP    $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
  proxy_set_header   Host $http_host; 
  proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
  proxy_set_header   Connection   "";
  proxy_http_version  1.1;
  proxy_cache one;
  proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;
  proxy_pass  http://my_node_site; # refer to the ubove node site

}
```

What's wrong with my settings?

PS: I found on **Firefox 38.x**, it works fine, the issue only exist on **Chrome 46.x**.
On chrome I didn't disable cache with developer tool(font file, and images has been cached correctly.)

Comment: which version you use?

Comment: Nginx, version 1.9.9

Comment: It is an old question, but if someone runs into this, please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35328096/1145053