# Cache resource for some time and then validate it using HTTP caching

Tags: http, cdn, cache-control, http-caching

Considering that the server responds with the following headers:

```
Cache-Control: public
Expires: <EXPIRATION DATE>
ETag: <HASH VALUE>
```

Both `<EXPIRATION DATE>` and the `<HASH VALUE>` are not changed if the underlying resource is not actually updated.

I'm I correct to expect the following:

- all intermediate proxy-servers (including the CDN) will consider this resource public and safe to cache.
- all intermediate proxy-servers (including the CDN) as well as browsers will consider this resource fresh until the `<EXPIRATION DATE>` and will return it from the cache without accessing the network. However, **after** the `<EXPIRATION DATE>` they all will use HTTP validation mechanism with **every** request to check if the resource is outdated.

So, if the resource is updated after the `<EXPIRATION DATE>` I can safely expect that all the clients will receive the fresh version of the resource with the next request (because HTTP validation will fail due to the ETag's change)?

I'm interested both from the standards perspective (RFCs) as well as from the real life perspective (e.g. known browser and proxy quirks).

---

I would like my resource to be fresh for e.g. one day from the time the file is actually updated on the server and to be always returned from the cache. However, after one day, I would like all the client to receive the fresh copy only if the file was actually changed (using HTTP validation mechanism).

Comment: I don't know if there are any "known browser and proxy quirks", but in terms of the standard your analysis is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As [Kevin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66889474/cache-resource-for-some-time-and-then-validate-it-using-http-caching#comment118248585_66889474) says:

> in terms of the standard your analysis is correct

It's difficult to answer in terms of "known browser and proxy quirks" without knowing your engineering requirements. It sounds like you may be serving static content; [consider services like S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089159/aws-serving-static-files-with-performance-in-mind) and CloudFront.

For this design, from your expectations:

> browsers will consider this resource fresh until the  and will return it from the cache without accessing the network

Most browsers will still reach out to the network when a resource is directly referenced, even when it's still fresh in their cache. That *should* be a conditional request, but it's still network traffic.([`immutable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936772/which-browsers-support-cache-control-immutable) may help.)

Any cache may evict the resource; for [one CDN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html):

> If a file in an edge location isn't frequently requested, CloudFront might evict the file

If your intention is to reduce load on your origin server, it's a good strategy. You're making correct use of `Expires`, `Cache-Control: public` and `ETag`, assuming you're also handling conditional requests correctly. In practice, you should:

- be ready for browsers to make more than a single request in a 24 hour period
- be ready to tune your CDN and confirm that it's respecting those headers, and that all requests lead to the same cache key
- expect more than a single request per day to your origin server