# PHP site not showing cache-control. Not caching anything

Tags: apache, caching

### INTRO

I have a task to fix existing site's problem that nothing is being cached (except for browser session). When closing session and opening browser again, page loads a lot of images, JS and CSS again. As I have ~60 items every time, there is a big load problem.

### PROBLEM

Looking at Chrome console, Audit shows *The following resources are missing a cache expiration...*
[image: Audit]

And in Network item in "Response Headers" doesn't even show "cache-control" line.
[image: Response Head]

### TRIED SOLUTIONS

I have set info in `.htaccess` file and made sure `mod_expires` is active:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

I added `Cache-control` meta-tag in html head that is also showing in page's code source so it is compiled.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public" content="max-age=604800">
```

And I'd like to add that it most likely isn't a server issue as production page's host has set it to a usual default.  (And I don't have access to that server anyways) 
I'd be super delighted, if someone could give me some pointers of what I am missing or haven't checked or simply don't understand.

**Added main.css headers**
[image]

### Thanks!

Comment: This might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401049/chrome-doesnt-cache-images-js-css

Comment: @eol I had set Cache-control header in html meta tag with max-age already.

Comment: In no particular order... 1) ETag should do exactly that, make assets get cached. 2) HTML meta tags will by no means affect any other resources 3) `<IfModule mod_expires.c>` means: "if the module is not available, just ignore my code and don't tell me about it" 4) PHP doesn't play any role in asset deliveries (unless it does, in which case you should explain how)

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks: For reference you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, although stupid (as I expected), but I didn't read about it anywhere and just forget about the need of it.

### Solution

It turned out all those things changed (as I said everything was activated on server, access files etc). And the problem was that I didn't **clear the cache after changing caching info**. Now after three days I started working on some CSS, needed to reset the cache and boom - all the new headers are active for all the items.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the headers through php since this is a php site.

```
<?php
  header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000"); //30days (60sec * 60min * 24hours * 30days)
?>
```

Also you can use the FilesMatch like this in your .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: activated mod_headers in apache server, added both `FilesMatch` and php `header()` and still nothing. Default header is `no-cache` and `max-age:0`

Comment: can you send a screenshot of `main.css` headers ?

Comment: Added to the question (last image)

Comment: as i noticed, there is no cache-control header in the `main.css`. This means that somehow the `.htaccess` file is not doing what it should. try adding the FilesMatch directive to the apache config file for the website, and restart apache.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruksHow you activated the mode_headers?

Comment: Thanks for the help - upvote for trying. Read my answer if You are interested in super-smart solution. xD